# Mercurial - finding a changeset in which file appeared

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking at a large repository and wondering about purpose of one of the files in it. I thought it would be helpful to find the changeset in which the file originally appeared. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with revsets (see `hg help revsets`), using the `adds(pattern)` function. It takes a pattern and matches all revisions in which this file appeared first (due to renames and deletions, this can match more than one revision). You can then use `hg log` to display all revisions in this revset.

Example:

```
hg log -r 'adds("strangefile.c")'
```

You can use a `glob:` or `re:` prefix for the pattern to specifically pick a glob pattern or a regular expression.